# Using builtins to store global variables across modules

Tags: python, namespaces, jupyter, built-in

I have a Jupyter notebook which I want to use simply to run a bunch of functions that are defined in a python 'helper' file. The notebook does however have a few variables which the user can change (so they are like constants I suppose). I want these variables to be accessible from the helper file too. I would prefer not to have to pass these variables to each function call in the notebook.

I have found that the following works when defining these variables in the notebook:

```
import builtins

builtins.my_variable = my_value
```

The variable 'my_variable' can now be used in both the Jupyter notebook and the helper file.

NOTE: After defining the variable in this way, if I type `help(builtins)` in the notebook and scroll all the way to the bottom, under the 'DATA' section I find my variable listed.

Another thing that works:

```
import helper
helper.my_variable = my_value
```

Could someone explain why/how these things works, if there are any problems with using them and if so, potentially a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

To start: I'd recommend passing the variables to the `helper` module functions, rather than relying on global state. If you need some sort of global state and don't want to pass it over and over again, consider grouping some of the functions into classes where the state is passed to the class's initializer and stored on the instance. That way, calling the methods of the instance implicitly passes along the instance, and therefore the required state, with minimal repetition. I'll provide a simple example at the bottom of this answer.

Modifying the contents of `builtins` will mean bloating the lookup of last resort location with your value. This can conceivably slow all code, everywhere (especially if it means resizing the `builtins` module's underlying `dict`, potentially making it no longer fit in cache).

From a future-proofing perspective, there have been [occasional proposals to optimize lookups in `builtins` based on its presumed static contents](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0329/); while most proposals handle the case of `builtins` being modified, the effects of said optimizations may be lost (reverting to just performing lookups on demand). This has precedent too; prior to CPython 3.3, it was recommended that all attributes of an instance be created before `__init__` completed, and no attributes should be removed or added to the instance afterwards (the value of a given attribute could still be changed). But in 3.2 and earlier releases, there was no real penalty for ignoring this advice. [Starting in 3.3, classes that followed this advice got a massive reduction in per instance memory overhead](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/); classes that didn't follow the advice gained nothing.

There are other issues with modifying `builtins`, e.g.:

1. Possibly causing the underlying `dict` for `builtins` to increase in size, reduce memory access locality
2. Possibly creating additional collisions looking up specific builtins (slowing access to useful builtins simply because your new attribute exists)
3. Potentially hiding errors in other modules, e.g. a module is supposed to create a variable with the same name you shoved in `builtins` locally, but either fails to do so and silently uses your definition, or worse, intentionally relied on the name not existing to lazily initialize its own attribute, and now never initializes it, using your definition instead
4. Making your code hard to maintain; if I see a reference to a variable named `foo` in a module, I expect to be able to find the definition in the module, or find the source of the definition by looking at the imports (`from x import *` syntax stymies this, which is why static code checkers often report `from x import *` as an error). If it's secretly being created in some otherwise unrelated module and shoved in `builtins` (or worse, being mutated from many different unrelated modules), I'm going to get angry at whoever committed that atrocity.

Point is, modifying `builtins` is a bad idea. It will likely work, but don't do it.

Your `helpers` module approach isn't completely terrible, though in practice I'd suggest defining the shared values in `helpers.py` directly [as aqual.abdullah suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659051/364696) and treating them as constants, rather than having some other module create them there (which causes many of the same issues as modifying `builtins`, just with more limited scope for problems).

The reason these approaches work is that modules are mostly just syntactic sugar around string keyed Python `dict`s. You're allowed to add new attributes to most (though not all) objects in Python, and modules are objects themselves (and not one of the exceptions to that general rule).

```
helper.my_variable = my_value
```

really boils down to just:

```
helper.__dict__['my_variable'] = my_value
```

and since the same `helper` is seen by all of its importers (a module is cached on first `import`, and all subsequent `import`s get back a reference to the same cached copy), all of them see the modification.

---

The better solution I mentioned at the top is to change:

```
# helpers.py
a = 1
b = 2

def func1():
    return a + b

def func2():
    return a * b

def func3():
    return a / b
```

with the caller doing:

```
>>> import helper
>>> helper.a = 5
>>> helper.func1()
```

to a class based design:

```
# helpers.py
class Helper:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def func1(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def func2(self):
        return self.a * self.b

    def func3(self):
        return self.a / self.b
```

where usage is:

```
>>> import helpers
>>> h = helpers.Helper(a=5)
>>> h.func1()
```

or for a single use of a given set of values:

```
>>> helpers.Helper(a=5).func1()
```

and use of the defaults would just be:

```
>>> helpers.Helper().func1()
```

This avoids problems with multiple threads (or reentrant code) making mutually incompatible changes to the global state of `helpers` (because now the state is stored in instances, which are owned and managed independently). Using an initializer with default arguments means you never lose the original defaults; you can always make a fresh copy.

Comment: Thanks! The 'make a class' method you describe sounds like an excellent idea. And thanks for the example.

Answer (score -1):

First, let me say that I try to avoid global state, now that being said sometimes it is unavoidable. In Python the easiest way to create global state is to just have a module with variables in it. For example,

```py
# constants.py
constant1 = 'A Constant'
constant2 = 'Another Constant'
constant3 = 'Absolutely last constant'
```

In your Jupyter notebook you can do something like:

```
import constants
```

and in the modules with your functions you can do the same.

Basically, your second approach is the way to go.

**CAVEAT** Python doesn't really have a notion of constants since you could do something like `constants.constant1 = 'Some new value'`, this would have the effect of changing the value for new assignments of `constants.constant1`.

Comment: So if I wanted to I could even make an **empty** python file `constants` and then just set its values in my main file by going `constants.constant1 = 'something'`, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, but if you are adding global constants on the fly you may want to think about organizing your code in a way that makes them available to the scope you actually need them in.